# Is there a command for `AS` in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, alias, sql-as

I'm wondering if there is a command like `AS` for postgres. Does anyone know if postges has this ability? I've tried to google it but it's a very difficult question to google :P I want to make a select statement and store it as a new table name. I want to say something like:

```sql
SELECT subj, user AS 'new' FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It's a reserved [SQL key word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in PostgreSQL. See Table C-1 at the linked documentation page.

It's typically used with [column labels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS).

> The AS keyword is optional, but only if the new column name does not
>   match any PostgreSQL keyword (see Appendix C).

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT subj, user FROM table_name
```

So, your new table will be ready.

Answer (score 2):

"I want to make a select statement and store it as a new table name" --

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT subj, user AS "new" FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to leave any changes in the schema, you can do something like this-

```
select new.* from (  
  select foo, bar from old  
) as new
```

Answer (score 1):

1. develop your query: `SELECT field AS new_field FROM table WHERE ...;`
2. If it runs ok, copy it
3. Go to `VIEW` and do that: `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW new_view AS <QUERY>;`
4. Save the view and use it as table.
5. enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In my way, you can do alias for the field and create view to store it. which ll act like table.

select subj, user as new from table_name;
By using the above query can get subj and new as a field.

And create view.

create or replace view_name as
select subj, user as new from table_name;

And just call
 select view_name;

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you can create the alias of a column or table with or without `AS`.

For example, you create `person` table, then insert 2 rows into it as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT,
  first_name VARCHAR(20),
  last_name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name) 
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith'), (2, 'David', 'Miller');
```

Now, you can create the aliases `f_n` and `l_n` of `first_name` and `last_name` column respectively with or without `AS` as shown below:

```sql
SELECT id, first_name AS f_n, last_name l_n FROM person;
             -- With `AS`   -- Without `AS`
```

```sql
SELECT person.id, person.first_name AS f_n, person.last_name l_n FROM person;
                           -- With `AS`          -- Without `AS`
```

Then, you can get the result below:

```sql
 id |  f_n  |  l_n
----+-------+--------
  1 | John  | Smith
  2 | David | Miller
(2 rows
```

And, you can create the aliases `p`, `f_n` and `l_n` of `person` table, `first_name` and `last_name` column respectively with or without `AS` as shown below:

```sql
SELECT id, f_n, l_n, p.id, p.f_n, p.l_n FROM person AS p(id, f_n, l_n);
                                           -- With `AS`
```

```sql
SELECT id, f_n, l_n, p.id, p.f_n, p.l_n FROM person p(id, f_n, l_n);
                                         -- Without `AS`
```

Then, you can get the result below:

```sql
 id |  f_n  |  l_n   | id |  f_n  |  l_n
----+-------+--------+----+-------+--------
  1 | John  | Smith  |  1 | John  | Smith
  2 | David | Miller |  2 | David | Miller
(2 rows)
```